# How to manually manage keys in Memorystore Redis in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

I have setup a Memorystore Redis with my Nodejs in Google App Engine. I wonder though how would I access my redis instance so I can manually manage(like `del`) keys?

There is [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance#connecting-compute-engine) accessing from Compute Engine but what about from GAE?

Comment: App Engine Standard does not have an interface (terminal, SSH, etc) for you to connect to for manually manipulating memorystore via telnet or other tools. App Engine Flexible does support SSH just like Compute Eingine.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: FYI: you can use SDK, see https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/libraries

Comment: Thanks @filip26. Will the SDK enable me to execute Redis commands on my memorystore redis instance?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar tutorial on how to connect your App Engine to Cloud Memorystore that you could find [here](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connect-redis-instance-standard).

Basically the steps consist in setting up [Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) and afterwards using the standard [nodejs Redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) library to interact with your Memorystore instance. Apart from this there are no more Cloud specific steps to follow, just write your code and have fun.

Separately, as filip26 pointed out you also have the [Google Cloud Memorystore](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/redis/latest/index.html) library, this is meant to manage Memorystore instances and configurations as you would do through the Cloud SDK or the Console. However they don'tserve to interact with the database in the sense of adding or deleting entries.

As a side note be aware that some Redis commands available in on-premises Redis servers are not allowed in Memorystore, you could find more about these limitations [here](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/reference/redis-configs#unmodifiable_configuration_parameters).